# What happens when I launch something like "gedit" which returns the prompt immediately?

Tags: linux, unix, process, prompt

In CentOS7.2, when I launch gedit (/usr/bin/gedit the version is 3.14.3)

```
$ gedit hoge.txt
```

then the prompt returns immediately.

I am pretty new for UNIX world but where does the process go?

When I already have opened gedit, it looks gedit try opening a new tab in the existing window. That is why I cannot see the process by

```
$ ps (without x)
```

if the existing gedit is invoked in another shell.

I kind answered myself, but I want to ask how can it be done?

gedit deals with many technical process under the OS?

I realized

```
firefox
```

also looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, gedit don't go to background when launched from terminal, but firefox does. So if I want to know what happens with firefox, I will run

```
ps -fu `whoami` | grep firefox
```

And look for its PID in the output (**18235** in that case):

```
me       18235  1900 20 jul28 ?        22:58:52 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Then I will run `pstree` like this:

```
pstree -Ahps 18235
```

And the output of `pstree` will show me the processes tree for launched `firefox`

```
init(1)---lightdm(1272)---lightdm(1893)---init(1900)---firefox(18235)-+-plugin-containe(8990)-+-{plugin-containe}(8992)
                                                                      |                       |-{plugin-containe}(8993)
                                                                      |                       `-{plugin-containe}(8994)
                                                                      |-{firefox}(18242)
                                                                      |-{firefox}(18243)
                                                                      |-{firefox}(18245)
                                                                      |-{firefox}(18246)
                                                                      |-{firefox}(18247)
```

It loks like firefox(18235) is attached to parent init(1900) who's attached to lightdm(1893), etc.

Comment: How can you do this? Because firefox is installed by su?

Comment: What do you mean installed by su? I recomend you to start reading about [bash job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control). It may help you to clear your doubts.

Comment: I am sorry. I confused you.. Maybe I should learn OS system...including bash of course